# Making a list of dictionaries pass-by-value

Tags: python, pass-by-value

I have a bit of headache in a list of dicts.

```
def funk(x):
    for i in x:
        i['a'] += 1
        print i

list1 = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':3, 'b':4}]
funk(list1)
print list1
```

this will output:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2}
{'a': 4, 'b': 4}
[{'a': 2, 'b': 2}, {'a': 4, 'b': 4}]
```

but I want to have this:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2}
{'a': 4, 'b': 4}
[{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':3, 'b':4}]
```

How do I make `list1` stay untouched?
eg: **`[{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':3, 'b':4}]`**

Comment: First of all, everything in Python is always pass-by-value. But every value in Python is a pointer to an object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`funk()` could make a copy of `x` and modify that copy instead of modifying the original `x`.

```
import copy

def funk(x):
    x = copy.deepcopy(x)
    for i in x:
        i['a'] += 1
        print i

list1 = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':3, 'b':4}]
funk(list1)
print list1
```

Comment: You should say a `deepcopy`.  Since `x` is a list holding `dicts`, a shallow copy isn't going to cut it.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I *HIGHLY* doubt that a simple `copy` of `x` works here.  Whether or not you copy the list, the objects you iterate over in the for loop are exactly the same ... So when you mutate an object, it should still show up.

Comment: @NPE -- Perhaps you should try it again ;-).  I just tried it and the result I get from the final `print list1` is the following: `[{'a': 2, 'b': 2}, {'a': 4, 'b': 4}]`.  Note that the `a` elements have been incremented.

Comment: @mgilson: Already have, you're right. Temporary blindness. Sorry for wasting your time. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the `copy` method of a dictionary might help you here:

```
def funk(x):
    for i in x:
        new_dict = i.copy()
        new_dict['a'] += 1
        print new_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, whether or not it's viable depends on the complexity/goal of your operation, but instead of modifying your list in-place, use a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to create a new one:

```
def funk(x):
    return [{key: value+1 if key == "a" else value for key, value in i.items()} for i in x]
```

In your example, you are printing the values, so this wouldn't be useful, but if your intent can be filled by having a new, altered list of dicts, it might be the best route.

Comment: I think it should read `value+1 if key == 'a' else value` instead of `value if key+1 == 'a' ...`.  Otherwise, I support this answer (+1)

Comment: @mgilson Indeed, just me not being careful.